# ggplot with categorical variables with two y axis

Tags: ggplot2

I would like to create a plot with categorical variables with two y axis.

I have already created the plot with one y axis. But I am not sure how to add the 2nd y axis in case of categorical variables in the x axis:

```
df %>%
ggplot(aes(Sample, Weight, color=Type,group=Type)) +
geom_point(alpha=10, size=.5) +
geom_smooth() +
ylab('Weight')
```

The second y axis could be the Height, which again has the same group: Type.

Please find below a dummy dataset:

```
#create data frame
df <- data.frame(Sample=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
                 Weight=c(53, 67, 89, 64, 84,77,55,78,99),
                 Height=c(167,198,177,167,199,178,165,190,188),
                 Type=factor(c("healthy","healthy","ill","healthy","ill","healthy","healthy","ill","healthy")))


p1<-df %>%
   ggplot(aes(Sample, Weight, color=Type,group=Type)) +
   geom_point(alpha=10, size=.5) +
   geom_smooth() +
   ylab('Weight')

p1 + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Please provide some dummy data for `df` so that we can render the plot with the given code.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have added dummy data above.

Answer (score 0):

The trick to secondary axis is that you should:

1. Transform your secondary variable to fit on the primary axis
2. Use the inverse transformation in the `sec_axis()` function.

In the example below, we use `Height / 2` make Height values more similar to Weight values. We use `trans = ~.x * 2` to scale the secondary axis correctly. I also added aesthetics that discriminate the two variables.

```r
library(ggplot2)

#create data frame
df <- data.frame(
  Sample=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
  Weight=c(53, 67, 89, 64, 84,77,55,78,99),
  Height=c(167,198,177,167,199,178,165,190,188),
  Type=factor(c("healthy","healthy","ill","healthy","ill","healthy","healthy","ill","healthy"))
)

ggplot(df, aes(Sample, Weight, color=Type,group=Type)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = "Weight")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = Height / 2, shape = "Height")) +
  geom_smooth(aes(linetype = "Weight")) +
  geom_smooth(aes(y = Height / 2, linetype = "Height")) +
  labs(linetype = "Variable", shape = "Variable") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Weight",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(
      name = "Height",
      trans = ~.x * 2
    )
  )
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula = 'y ~ x'
#> # Bunch of warnings I censored for brevity
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-02-14 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much, it looks exactly the way I wanted it to look. However when I run the code I get the following error: Error in sec_axis(name = "Height", transform = ~.x * 2) : 
  unused argument (transform = ~.x * 2)

Comment: Oops yes, that should be `trans` instead of `transform`.